# Open 2 windows javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I use javascript to redirect the current page and also open another popup window! 
would that be possible? is there a risk? thank you

Update:

```
  I am trying now to: 
  var myid=  "<xsl:value-of select="@ID" />"
  which works for
  document.location.href = http://... + myid
 but won't work for 
 window.open=("http://... "+ myid)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong. the is no value with windo.open

Answer (score 2):

## 1 open new window

```
window.open("http://stackoverflow.com/")
```

## 2 redirect

```
window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com/"
```

Note: order is important here.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer stating that the order here is what's really important!

Comment: @FAA do you mean a url param? If so you can just apply it directly to the first param, e.g. window.open("http://stackoverflow.com?favnum=1"). If you mean other params for the window.open function, you  can see them here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: I am trying to do this: var myid = "<xsl:value-of select="@ID" />"; any idia of the correct way. thanks

Comment: @FAA I would need to see a larger sample of your code to know for sure. From the little I know of xsl, you can't write a value-of directly to a javascript var like that. You could try writing it out to a hidden div and reading the value back out using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect:

```
window.location.href = "http://someothersite.com";
```

Popup:

```
window.open("http://somepopup.com","newWindowNameHere");
```

There are various features you can specify on your new window. See [this reference.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open)

Answer (score 1):

You can make javascript load a new page by changing the value of `location.href`

You can make javascript open a new popup window by using `window.open()`

FYI many browsers and addons will either prompt a visitor to allow/deny the popup, or flat out deny it.

Answer (score 1):

Use can use window.open to open a new window:

```
window.open("http://www.example.com");
```

You can update the document's location to do a simple redirect:

```
document.location = "http://www.example.com";
```

The draw backs of doing this is that additional windows tend to annoy users if they are not expecting it and some browsers/pop-up blockers will simply not allow the new window to open.